# Custom Typecaster with ActiveAttr Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-attr

I would like to create a custom Typecaster for the ActiveAttr Gem.

I have a `Package` class:

```
class Package

  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :quantity, :type => Integer
  attribute :detail
  attribute :type
  attribute :order

  def shipping

  end
end
```

and I have `Order` class

```
class Order

  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :id, :type => Integer

  def test

  end

end
```

In the Package class I want to use `attribute :order, :type => OrderTypecaster` because when I create a new package (`p = Package.new(params['package']`) I would like to set the Order id attribute automatically.

Is this possible?

I'm using Rails 3.2.13

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem without create a custom Typecaster.
In Package class I wrote two simple methods:

```
  def order=(value)
    @order = Order.new(value)
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.new
  end
```

Now when I call Package.new(params['package']) the order id is automatically setted.
I don't know if this is the best solution but works well, any better solution is welcome. :)

Tks guys!